# Track current position in typeahead list with observables

Tags: typescript, angular, reactive-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm working at a TypeScript autocomplete component (for Angular 2, although this is not core to question) and I'd like to manage most (or all) of it through observables in RxJs (5.0.0-beta.8). I'm having problems with tracking current item position in the list of suggestions when acting through up/down arrow keys: the index remains stuck at 0.

All the following logic is set aside in a separate `class` that receives input observables and produces output observables to subscribe to (that's why is not strictly related to Angular 2). Client code subscribes to output observables correctly.

Here's some code:

```ts
// Component responsible for managing only the list of suggestions
// It receives inputs from text field and it produces outputs 
// as current index in list, when to hide list, etc.
class AutocompleteListDriver {
  currentIndex$: Observable<number>;
  doClose$: Observable<void>;
  // ...

  constructor(...
    matches$: Observable<string[]>, // list of suggestions matching text in field
    keyUp$: Observable<KeyboardEvent>, // keyup events from text field
    keyDown$: Observable<KeyboardEvent>, // keydown events from text field
    ...) {

    const safeMatches$ = matches$
      .startWith([]);  // start with a clear, known state internally

    // when list is empty, component is hidden at rest:
    // detect keys only when component is visible
    const isActive$ = safeMatches$
      .map(matches => matches.length !== 0);

    const activeKeyUp$ = keyUp$
      .withLatestFrom(isActive$)
      .filter(tuple => tuple[1]) // -> isActive
      .map(tuple => tuple[0]);   // -> keyboardEvent

    this.currentIndex$ = safeMatches$
      .switchMap(matches => {
        const length = matches.length;
        console.log('length: ' + length);

        const initialIndex = 0;

        const arrowUpIndexChange$ = activeKeyUp$
          .filter(isArrowUpKey)
          .map(_ => -1);

        const arrowDownIndexChange$ = activeKeyUp$
          .filter(isArrowDownKey)
          .map(_ => +1);

        const arrowKeyIndexChange$ = Observable
          .merge(arrowUpIndexChange$, arrowDownIndexChange$)
          .do(value => console.log('arrow change: ' + value));

        const arrowKeyIndex$ = arrowKeyIndexChange$
          .scan((acc, change) => {
            // always bound result between 0 and length - 1
            const index = limitPositive(acc + change, length);

            return index;

          }, initialIndex)
          .do(value => console.log('arrow key index: ' + value))
          .startWith(0);

        return arrowKeyIndex$;
      })
      .do(value => console.log('index: ' + value))
      .share();
  }
}
```

The idea is that everytime a new list of matches (suggestions) is emitted, current index in list should start a new *"sequence"*, so to say. Each of those sequences starts from 0, listens for increments/decrements due to arrow down/up keys, accumulate those by taking care not to go beyond lower/upper limits.

*To start a new sequence* to me it translates to `switchMap`. But with such code, console only shows:

```
length: 5
index: 0
```

and arrow up/down keys are not detected at all (tried inserting other logs on `arrowDownIndexChange$`), so no more logs and no effect in final component. It's like if their observables are not *subscribed* anymore, but as far as I know `switchMap` should subscribe to the latest generated sequence and drop/unsubscribe from all previous ones.

Just to try, I used `mergeMap` instead: in this case arrow keys are detected, but of course the problem is that all sequences (due to previous moments when matches where set) are merged together and their values overlaps each other. Apart from this being incorrect anyway, from time to time the matches list will go empty, so there's always a point where current index sequence always stays at 0. This sequence merges and overlaps with all the others, giving a net result of index stuck at 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Anyway you could make this into a plunkr? That would make it easier to track down the issue.

Comment: the component is up [on github](https://github.com/BrainCrumbz/ng2-autocomplete-words-example/) with its example application. [This is](https://github.com/BrainCrumbz/ng2-autocomplete-words-example/blob/ec42b926f04abea6a722673a7389363196fa36a5/src/client/autocomplete/acw-list-driver.ts#L82) the `switch()` call. I understand it's not the same as a plunker, but maybe as a first step this can help playing at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Apparently my former findings through rxjs docs where wrong (and of course I got this **after** writing down the question, then looking for more insights).

It seems that `switchMap` is not the right tool for the case. What I should use is `switch()` instead. And this should not come as a surprise, coming from a .Net Reactive Extensions background... but I don't know why the naming changes between languages often catch me wrong.

Working solution should be instead:

```ts
this.currentIndex$ = safeMatches$
  // use map to generate an "observable of observables"
  // (so called higher-order observable)
  .map(matches => {
    const length = matches.length;
    // ...
  })
  // "unwrap" higher order observable, by always 
  // keeping subscribed to the latest inner observable
  .switch()
  .do(value => console.log('index: ' + value))
```

**EDIT**
That was not enough. I also had to drop `activeKeyUp$` in favour of raw `keyUp$`.

If anyone has other suggestions (or explanations on current behaviour, e.g. activeKeyUp/keyUp), please feel free to answer.

**EDIT #2**
Thanks to @paulpdaniels comment: it turns out that the only real issue was that `activeKeyUp$` Vs `keyUp$` bug. Replacing `map().switch()` with `switchMap()` did not harm functionality in any way.

Comment: `switchMap()` is (should be) semantically identical to `map()` + `switch()`. So if you are getting different behaviors between the two, that may be a bug.

Comment: @paulpdaniels feel free to post that sugestion as an answer so I can accept it. It is the real answer for future readers